# Ansible docker_network fails on missing docker module

Tags: docker, ansible, docker-network

I keep getting the following error on the "Create a network" step of my Ansible role on the first run. Every second time I run the ansible script it seems to be working. Am I missing something? Does docker need more time to initiate?

```
fatal: [192.168.1.102]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to import the required Python library (Docker SDK for Python: docker (Python >= 2.7) or docker-py (Python 2.6)) on test's Python /usr/bin/python3. Please read module documentation and install in the appropriate location, for example via `pip install docker` or `pip install docker-py` (Python 2.6). The error was: No module named 'docker'"}
```

Ansible docker role:

```
- name: Install aptitude using apt.
  apt:
    name: aptitude
    state: latest
    update_cache: yes
    force_apt_get: yes

- name: Install prerequisites.
  apt:
    name: '{{ packages }}'
    update_cache: yes
    state: latest
  vars:
    packages:
      - apt-transport-https
      - ca-certificates
      - curl
      - software-properties-common

- name: Add Docker GPG key.
  apt_key:
    id: 9DC858229FC7DD38854AE2D88D81803C0EBFCD88
    url: https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg
    state: present

- name: Add Docker repository.
  apt_repository:
    repo: deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/{{ ansible_distribution | lower }} {{ ansible_distribution_release }} stable

- name: Install Docker.
  apt:
    name: '{{ packages }}'
    update_cache: yes
    state: latest
  vars:
    packages:
      - docker-ce
      - docker-compose

- name: Create "docker" group.
  group:
    name: docker
    state: present

- name: Add remote "ubuntu" user to "docker" group.
  user:
    name: '{{ run_as_user }}'
    groups: docker
    append: yes

- name: Create a network.
  docker_network:
    name: '{{ network }}'
```

Comment: Maybe you are right, if it works the second time then everything is correct. You can try adding "pause" at a few places and try.

Comment: Did you actually do on the target what the error message is verbosely suggesting? => `pip install docker`

Comment: To add to the correct comment by @Zeitounator you can also install that package via your playbook, so it's always correct on the remote machine via `- pip: name=docker state=present`

Comment: I was indeed missing the dependency on the machine ansible was installing on. Pip install worked.